# Do we skip crossfire events in Extraction when playing with less than 4 players?

Tags: shadowrun-crossfire

The rules say to use the normal Crossfire rules but the mission seems to already compensate for lesser numbers by modifying the round actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you will still flip crossfire cards as the rules for extraction say to follow the crossfire rules of a standard crossfire game. In a standard game you flip it on the first turn with four players, second turn with three players and the third turn with two players. The only change to what is being flipped is obstacles which are flipped according to a tracker in the mission instructions.

Need to remember that crossfire cards are where a lot of the difficulty comes from. I have lost count of how many games have been lost in the last round just because of the crossfire card that is flipped.

[Rules](http://cdn.shadowruntabletop.com/wp-content/uploads/CAT27700_Crossfire_Full%20Rules.pdf?d131f9)

Page 20 of the rules

> Obstacles and Crossfire: Use the normal Crossfire rules. Flip
>   obstacles as instructed for each step of the mission track.
>   Flipped obstacles start facing the Client, but the runners
>   can protect the Client. At the start of each runner’s turn, a
>   non-staggered runner can move one obstacle facing the Client
>   to face them instead, if that obstacle’s color matches their
>   role color. This choice must be made before any obstacle abilities
>   that would trigger at the start of a runner’s turn.
>   Obstacles will attack runners they’re facing, as normal, but
>   when a runner becomes staggered, move all obstacles facing
>   that runner to face the Client at the end of that turn.

Page 19

> Playing with Fewer than Four Runners: If there are only three
>   runners, do not flip a Crossfire card at the start of the first
>   round. If there are only two runners, do not flip a Crossfire
>   card at the start of the first or second rounds.